# Displaying a json object on groups using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I just returned a `users` object in json format from the server. This `users` object is composed of multiple users each having attributes like
`first_name`, 
`last_name`, 
`phone` 
`email` and
`role`.

Now i want to display this object on my html page using angularjs. But I want to group users according to their `role` attribute so that each table on that page will hold a different kind of user (e.g admin, owner etc.)

I already tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-if="user.role == admin">
        // list all admins here
    </div>
    <div ng-if="user.role == owners">
        // list all owners here
    </div>
</div>
```

But nothing appears on the page. I am new to angularjs by the way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `ng-if="user.role == 'admin'"` missing single quotes

Comment: Thank you very much @taguenizy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a filter is maybe a more "angularish" way of doing it.

```
    <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{role:'admin'}">
       {{user.name}}
    </div>
```

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/DGVXOud22ICkFgL1G7EF?p=preview) is a fork of @Sajeetharan's solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-if="user.role === 'admin'">
        {{user.name}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="user.role === 'owners'">
         {{user.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/NzX9vafKLQkmdBR20wVK?p=preview)**